# Compiling on x64 Eclipse with x32 JDK on x64 Windows for x32 Server

Tags: java, eclipse, websphere

okay, without sounding ambigous perhaps i already have ... can someone tell me if there are any challenges when having this kinda collaboration or setup. This is a rather a wide question but my interest is more on whether it is safe to compile with this kinda setup and if Eclipse will throw an excpetions. Am thinking Win probably has nothing to do with the compilation anyway

Comment: Easy way to check is to write something and see if it works or throws an error :)

Answer (score 2):

64 bit Eclipse will not work with 32 bit JDK, as SWT will complain when you try to bring up the Eclipse UI. However, if you compile in headless mode (using ANT scripts or something similar) things should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can define in Eclipse any number of JDKs, including 32 - bit versions:

So you can install the 32bit JDK, then add it to Eclipse (Window/Preferences/Java/Installed JREs) and add it to your project in Properties/Java Build Path/Libraries tab, "Add Library" button.

It should work fine. Warning: make sure x64 Eclipse is using the 32bit JVM to start, it simply won't as it needs a 64bit version.

HOWEVER: bytecode compiled with a 64bit JVM will run on 32bit JVMs. Only native libraries will cause you problems.

Answer (score 0):

As Deepak said, you can't run 64-bit Eclipse on a 32-bit JVM (or vice-versa). But you can run 32-bit Eclipse and JVM on 64-bit Windows. The trick is getting the right JRE/JDK download from the Oracle site, since when it sees your browser is 64-biut it wants to force 64-bit JRE on you (at least, it did the last time I tried).

In any case, if you're talking about an application that doesn't use any native code (eg, NOT an Eclipse RCP app), you should be just fine developing on one platform and running on another.